# Pyautogui wont type this

Tags: python, pyautogui

I made this program for alt tabbing ant typing.
But it doesnt work and i can't find the error.

```
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'tab')
    pyautogui.typewrite(i)
    pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
```

Comment: The problem is in line 4

Comment: Is it better now?